# Change of variables and Rewriting an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, change-of-variable

Given the second order ODE:
\begin{equation}
y'' + yy' + xy^4 = 0
\end{equation}

with a change of variables of:
\begin{align}
r & = xy & s& = \ln x \\
y & = re^{-s} & x & = e^s\\
\end{align}

the example I am looking at then states the ODE can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
s_{rr} = (r^4 - r^2 +2r)s^3_r + (r-3)s^2_r
\end{equation}

I am battling to fill in the blanks as to how they arrive at that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below a way for the change of variables :

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, could you refer me to a textbook or online notes that I can follow to solidify my understanding of the method?  I have so many examples I am working through.

Comment: Sorry I have no specific reference. I suggest to not use prime or subsript like $s'$ or $s_r$ I prefer $\frac{ds}{dr}$. But everyone does as he pleases.

Comment: I tend to just use what ever form is being used by the text I am looking at. This author, Arrigo, uses the subscript $s_r$